# Validating parameter as a class in Squeak Smalltalk

Tags: smalltalk, squeak

How can I validate a parameter as a class object?  For example, if I want to validate aparameter as string I could write `param1 isString`.  Is there something like `isClass`?

Comment: You might consider accepting an answer or indicate what's missing

Answer (score 3):

As others have pointed out, `isKindOf:` and `isMemberOf:` are your friends when you're trying to figure this kind of thing out, but calling those methods is *usually* a kind of code smell.  There are almost always better ways to do this, which I'll break into two categories:

1. **Implement the method on all relevant classes, doing the right thing on each.**  For example, if I were writing a video game, then, rather than testing what kind of object I'm getting it and telling it what to do next, I can instead just implement a `performNextStep` function on all game objects, then leave it to each object to figure out what it ought to do.
2. **Test for functionality, not class membership.** Rather than checking whether something `isKindOf:` a class, instead check whether it `respondsTo: aMethod`, and  call it if it does.  This also means that classes that have acquired a valid method, but are not in the initial hierarchy you were anticipating, can still be passed around—doubly important if you're using Traits, where there may not be a single class hierarchy to test with.

Answer (score 2):

You can test whether your parameter inherits from `Class` or `Metaclass`:

```
String isKindOf: Class orOf: Metaclass => true
"If you don't want Metaclasses, simply use isKindOf: Class"
String class isKindOf: Class orOf: Metaclass => true
'foo' isKindOf: Class orOf: Metaclass => false
```

However, it might be preferable to implement the operation you want to perform on `Class` (and any other relevant objects) itself, so you can just perform `someOp` without actually validating your inputs.

---

If your input is a String and you want to get the Class with the according name (if it exists), you can use:

```
Smalltalk classNamed: 'String'
```

Comment: If you want to cover case of Class, Metaclass and Trait, you also have message #isBehavior in Squeak.<br>